# How to verify whether a function is called on a mock object who parameter has a lambda expression

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito

Let's say I've a function named

```
fun doSomething() {
    customObject.callThis(10, 20)
}
```

And customObject is an object of class `CustomObject` and it's mocked using Mockito. The below is the Unit test one will write for the above code.

```
@Test
fun doSomething() {
    // Call the doSomething() function
    verify(customObject).callThis(10, 20)
}
```

This works perfectly. Now my doubt comes when we write `doSomething` function as below.

```
fun doSomething() {
    customObject.callThis(10, { navigation.finish() })
}
```

Where navigation is a mock object of class Navigation. Now, how do I test the above function?

Comment: I would verify that the `finish()` method is called on the passed in object. And perhaps use an `InOrder` if there are ordering guarantees on the API.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Can you please expand on the solution. I didn't get what you meant. Not sure what InOrder meant as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using mockito-kotlin, you could do something like the following:

```
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.inOrder
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.eq
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.any

inOrder {
    verify(customObject).callThis(eq(10), any())
    verify(navigation).finish()
}
```

Comment: More than any() I would say eq(value) is a good learning for me.